# Arranging app icons in a 'wheel'

Tags: android

I need my home page design for a sample website.

My plan is to arrange icons in a half circle.
How can i implement layout in android?

Can someone suggest same design for iOS too?
My sample design[image: sample design]

Comment: You can use "RelativeLayout" and by giving margins you can set them.

Comment: Can you put them in a `table` or something like that? That way the space between the images can be controlled. A `GridView` is also an alternative.

Comment: @Dhivya Use Absolute layout to create this design. You can fix your icon based on x,y position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following layout to achieve that. Modify as per your requirement.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Satellite Menu as an option for displaying circular arranged menus. It also has good animation effect.. 
For reference and source code [refer here](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu).

It works in **API Level 7 (2.1)** and above.